# Routed Commands Event Tunneling

Tags: wpf

WPF is having two diff classes for commands. RoutedCommand and RoutedUICommand. When I understood the difference I came to know that RoutedCommand is having capability for Routed Events (for bubbling and tunneling purpose.) But When I am binding command with a particular control, why would I need bubbling and tunneling for commands? Please guide me.

Regards,
Priyank

Comment: Bubble to send the command up the visual tree; tunnel to send it down.